# Forcing FullSimplify to use user defined functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is it possible to simplify the expression using user-defined functions? For example if I define:

```
m[l_, x_] := Sum[x^i/i, {i, 1, l - 1}]
```

I would like

```
x + x^2/2 // FullSimplify
```

to returns

> ```
> m[3, x]
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the second argument of `FullSimplify` to specify (hopefully not too long)  a list of equalities involving the forms that you wish to detect and keep in the input expression:

```
ClearAll[m]
m[l_, x_] := Sum[x^i / i, {i, 1, l-1}]

FullSimplify[10 + x + x^2/2, Array[m[#, x] == HoldForm[m[#, x]] &, 10]]
```

> 10 + m[3, x]

```
FullSimplify[5 + x + 5 (x + x^2/2) + y Log[x + x^2/2 + x^3/3], 
   Array[m[#, x] == HoldForm[m[#, x]] &, 10]]
```

> 5 + m[2, x]+ 5 m[3, x] + y Log[m[4, x]]